# How can I save a data set created using the memisc package in r?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I'm using memisc to read in a massive SPSS file in order to reshape it. This seems to work very well.

However, I'd also like to be able to output the results to an SPSS-readable file that retains labels and descriptions--after all, this is the advantage of using the data-set construct memisc has set up.

I've searched the memisc documentation for any mention of an export, save, or output function. I've also tried passing a memisc data set to write.foreign (from the foreign package).

**Why am I doing this in the first place?** Reshaping massive data files in SPSS is a pain. R makes it easy. But the folks I'm doing this for want to maintain the labels and descriptions.

Thanks!

Comment: Check out: https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/2439148